# QtQuick colour palette for disabled widgets

Tags: qt, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2, qqmlapplicationengine

I am working on a Qt (QML) application that requires darker color palette. Based on some examples I created a `qtquickcontrols2.conf` file with the following content:

```
[Controls]
Style=Fusion

[Fusion\Palette]
AlternateBase=#353535
Base=#191919
BrightText=red
Button=#353535
ButtonText=white
Highlight=#2a82da
HighlightedText=gray
Link=#2a82da
Text=white
ToolTipBase=white
ToolTipText=white
Window=#353535
WindowText=#dddddd
```

The colour palette works just fine for active mode of widgets. However, disabled widgets look exactly the same as active ones. I did not find a way to add colours for disabled widgets to the config file. It seems that it can't be done.

Then I had an idea to create lighter version of active palette in application main.

```cpp
QPalette& updateDisabledColors(QPalette &palette)
{
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::Window, palette.window().color().lighter());
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::WindowText, palette.windowText().color().lighter());
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::Base, palette.base().color().lighter());
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::AlternateBase, palette.alternateBase().color().lighter());
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::Text, palette.text().color().lighter());
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::Button, palette.button().color().lighter());
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::ButtonText, palette.buttonText().color().lighter());
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::BrightText, palette.brightText().color().lighter());
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::Link, palette.link().color().lighter());
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::Highlight, palette.highlight().color().lighter());
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::HighlightedText, palette.highlightedText().color().lighter());

    return palette;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

// Tried to change palette here also

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty()) {
        return -1;
    }

    auto palette = app.palette();
    palette = updateDisabledColors(palette);
    app.setPalette(palette);

    return app.exec();
}
```

The palette acquired from the `app` is not the one defined in `qtquickcontrol2.conf`.

What is the proper way to modify palette colours for disabled widgets when using QML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, setting the Fusion style Palette in `qtquickcontrols2.conf` does not update the default `Q[Gui]Application` palette. But the opposite works -- the default `Controls2` palette is the system-wide default `QPalette` which can be set with `Q[Gui]Application::setPalette()`. So you could set all the color groups in C++ code, like you do now for just the `Disabled` group.

Looking at the [relevant code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtquickcontrols2/src/quickcontrols2/qquickstyle.cpp.html#_ZN18QQuickStylePrivate11readPaletteERK14QSharedPointerI9QSettingsE), it also looks like you can specify a `Disabled` subgroup in `qtquickcontrols2.conf` (e.g. `Fusion/Palette/Disabled`). I'm not sure which versions of Qt this is available in, nor do I see this documented anywhere.

ADDED: Looks like the `Palette` and subgroups are read from conf file since at least [Qt 5.10](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/quickcontrols2/qquicktheme.cpp?h=5.10#n105) (which is also when the [Control::palette](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html#palette-prop) property was introduced).

Comment: Thank you very much. Using Palette\Disabled works fine with Qt 5.13.